# Generate RSA signature in Java but verify the signature failed in C++

Tags: java, c++, openssl, cryptography, crypto++

Recently I need to use RSA to sign a string in Java, and  verify the signature in C++.

In Java, now I think every thing is OK,I create public.keystore and private.keysore and can sign&&veify the data successfully.But when I try to verify it in C++, it shows signature failed.

Here is my Java code, in java, I sign the data to a base64String, and save it on my local as "sig.dat", the data which I signed I save it as "signed.dat":

> ```
> public static String sign(byte[] data, String privateKey) throws Exception {
>     byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(privateKey);
>     Base64.decodeBase64(privateKey);
>     PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
>     KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
>     PrivateKey privateK = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
>     Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
>     signature.initSign(privateK);
>     signature.update(data);
>     return Base64.encodeBase64String(signature.sign());
> }
> ```

Generate sig.dat and signed.dat file:

```
String signStr = RSAUtils.sign("123".getBytes(), privateKey2);
boolean result = RSAUtils.verify("123".getBytes(), publicKey2, signStr);
System.out.println("result:" + result);


FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("signed.dat");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
dos.write("123".getBytes());
dos.close();

FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("sig.dat");
DataOutputStream dos2 = new DataOutputStream(fos2);
dos2.write(Base64.decodeBase64(signStr));
```

Here is my c++ code, I load the file : "signed.dat" and "sig.dat" to use API to verify it:

```
void Verify()
{   
    //Read public key
    CryptoPP::ByteQueue bytes;
    FileSource file("pubkey.txt", true, new Base64Decoder);
    file.TransferTo(bytes);
    bytes.MessageEnd();
    RSA::PublicKey pubKey;
    pubKey.Load(bytes);

    RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Verifier verifier(pubKey);

    //Read signed message
    string signedTxt;
    FileSource("signed.dat", true, new StringSink(signedTxt));
    string sig;
    FileSource("sig.dat", true, new StringSink(sig));

    string combined(signedTxt);
    combined.append(sig);

    cout << "signedTxt------------:" << signedTxt<< endl;
    cout << "sig------------:" << sig << endl;
    //Verify signature
    try
    {
        StringSource(combined, true,
            new SignatureVerificationFilter(
                verifier, NULL,
                SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION
            )
        );
        cout << "Signature OK" << endl;
    }
    catch (SignatureVerificationFilter::SignatureVerificationFailed &err)
    {
        cout << err.what() << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is openssl in the tags? Aren't you using crypto++?

Comment: Did you try to use `openssl` to verify the signature?

Comment: @Slava, No..... but now I want to try openssl as till now I still don't find the solution.

Comment: I mean use openssl executable, not to rewrite your program btw. At least you may find out where is the culprit.

Answer (score -2):

```
string combined(signedTxt);
combined.append(sig);
```

It doesn't make sense to append the digital signature to the data whose signature is to be checked. The digital signature didn't include itself when you created it: why therefore would you include it in the data to be verified?

Comment: I do this according the doc wiki, Signature Scheme (PKCS v1.5), https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography#Signature_Schemes